# Do I need visual studio license?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, licensing

I am a novice freelancer providing .NET solutions. Currently I have a Student version of Visual Studio that I am working. But, If I want to deliver solutions to the clients, do I need to have buy the VS license?

For instance, I got a requirement from a client (does'nt have VS license) to build a web application in godaddy. In this case, does we both need to purchase license?

Is there any alternative like developing the application in web developer express edition and publish that using Nant tools?

Thanks in advance,
Kris

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Visual Studio Express edition. There are no limitations regarding commercial use.

From [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx)

> **Can I use Express Editions for
>   commercial use?** Yes, there are no
>   licensing restrictions for
>   applications built using Visual Studio
>   Express Editions.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft just released a new version of Visual Studio - [Visual Studio Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-community-vs).

It is the equivalent of Visual Studio 2013 Professional but free for students, open source software projects, and small teams (less than 5).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer and this is not a site to get legal questions answer. But in general, you cannot use student versions to deliver commercial products. Also, depending on the software each machine has to use it's own license of the software.

Comment: FYI - I am not using student version to build the commercial products.I use student version for just practice.

Comment: In order for you to develop something that will go to a client, yes you would need a non-student version, or you could use the express editions since those don't have restrictions. If your client is going to use Visual Studio (not just whatever you deliver), then yes probably they would need their license. Again not a lawyer but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Visual Studio 2010 Express, then there's a [thread here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/0782e1b0-db87-4de3-b79d-ba56a481e750) on the MSDN forums that states: "Provided that you comply with all the License Terms for a particular Express release, the 2010 Express SKUS can be used to create commercial software."